# Improve Thumbnail Preview Speed for Images in Shared Folders

Tags: windows-7, images, performance, networking, thumbnails

At my office we have an Apple Server running Xserver which, among other things, we use as network storage.

Previously we had our Graphic Designer setup on a Windows Vista machine, and everything was working great. Recently we upgraded his machine to a faster one running Windows 7- unfortunately it has caused performance problems when it comes to using the network storage. Both machines are connected to the Apple Server via Gigabit Ethernet connections.

Essentially the issue is that, while browsing our catalogue of images **the Windows 7 machine** takes an **unreasonably long** amount of time **to generate thumbnail previews** of the images, the Windows Vista machine had/still has no issue rapidly producing thumbnail previews when viewing the same network folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% sure if the instructions from below MS KB would help but you can certainly try:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Other people with similar issue had got their problem fixed by above kb article.